# Are my Rails methods/helper functions executing every time anyone does a GET request to the server, in parallel? Is this an issue?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My website is mostly to display results, so the admin enters the results and they are rendered nicely for the users/clients. Currently, in my main_controller.rb and other controllers I have functions for the main index page...

```
 def index
        
         @next_tournament               = helpers.next_tournament()
         @last_tournament               = helpers.last_tournament()
         @last_tournament_date_display  = helpers.last_tournament_date_display(@last_tournament)
         @next_tournament_date_display  = helpers.next_tournament_date_display(@next_tournament)
         @current_season                = @last_tournament.season_year  
         @aoys                          = helpers.display_aoy(@last_tournament.id)
         @aoy_diff                      = helpers.aoy_point_diff(@aoys)
         @individual_winners            = helpers.individual_winners(@last_tournament.id)
         @team_winners                  = helpers.team_winners(@last_tournament.id)
         @big_bass_winners              = helpers.big_bass_winners(@last_tournament.id)
         @total_club_stats              = helpers.total_club_stats()
         @annual_club_stats             = helpers.annual_club_stats(@current_season  )
         ...
        
    end
```

Does this mean, that for every person that navigates to my main index page the server will re-run these functions and spit out the result?

I'm trying to understand what happens on the server side. Would this be a problem? Most of these functions would only change when a new result is entered. Is it best practice to do something in the code, so that the function is only re-ran when any of the variables in the equation change, and otherwise static?

Comment: Yes it is rerun for every visitor, but it should not be a problem. It is not done in parallel. It is how your server is configured and how much concurrency it handles that will tell how many users can be served simultaneously. Also what is `helpers` ?

Comment: helpers is just a ruby/rails syntax for calling methods within from *_helper.rb files within your rails controllers